# String functions in Cloud Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to remove a plus signal at string returned by request.auth.phone_number. For that, I've tried to use the replace function, but I've received the following  error: "Function not found error: Name: [replace].";

```
match /test/{id} {
  allow read, update, delete, create: if request.auth != null && (resource.data.items[request.auth.token.phone_number.replace('+', '')] == true || resource == null);
}
```

This works fine when I run at Realtime Database. For instance:

```
"tests": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth.uid.replace('+', '') === '5521999991234'"
  }
}
```

Is there any way to use string functions like "contains(), replace(), toLowerCase()" and so on, in Cloud Firestore Databases?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a function like this :

```
function replace(string, replace, by) {
  return string.split(replace).join(by)
}
```

and use it so..

```
replace('+3312312345', '+', '')
```

in your example :

```
match /test/{id} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null && 
  (resource.data.items[replace(request.auth.token.phone_number, '+', '')] 
  == true || resource == null);
}

// below your rules
function replace(string, replace, by) {
  return string.split(replace).join(by)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firestore security rules use a completely different language than Realtime Database.

You can see a list of all methods available on string objects in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String).  The only thing you are asking to do that's actually available is [lower](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#lower) and [matches](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches).

Answer (score 2):

Update: A `.replace()` method was added a few months ago. You can now do things like

```
request.auth.token.phone_number.replace('\\+', '')
```

Note that the first argument is a regex formatted as a string.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String.html#replace